# Trying to add a literal in ASP.NET but it won't alllow it because it contains code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0, literals

This is my code:

```
Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"" + Urls.FindCSS("jquery-modalpopup.css") + "\" type=\"text/css\" />"));
```

I'm new to ASP.NET and to using Literals but from what I read this should be valid yet I get this exception at runtime:

`The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).`

I searched for similar questions of course but the `use  <%#` solution aka databinding doesn't work for me.

If you have any solutions or recommendations I'm listening.

Comment: What does Urls.FindCSS("jquery-modalpopup.css") return?

Comment: It finds the css file in that it is no problem the problem is in how I dynamicaly add a link to said file in the ascx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `<% ... %>` from your header and use another Literal instead.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's just not clicking to me, what should I do in more detail, I'm kind of in a need of a solution which implies as little refactoring as possible.

Comment: The error says that Page.Header contains <% ... %> block you need to check your aspx file to see it, you can't make additions to controls collection because of this block, so eather you need to remove the block from the header and replace it with a literal control or you need to add the new content using another <% ... %> block

Comment: This is it but unfortunately it will require a lot of refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to use

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("jquery-modalpopup",
    Urls.FindCSS("jquery-modalpopup.css"));
```

Instead of adding the j-script include through a literal, thus avoiding to call `Controls.Add`.

Apologies, I just found out that this doesn't add the script in the header, it could maybe still help.